# What is proper way to consume inbound stream of ReactorNettyWebSocketClient

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I try to learn reactive programming with Spring Reactor Webflux. particularly at this following example i try to figure out how to compose the processing pipeline properly, to consume the inbound stream of a Websocket connection using ReactorNettyWebSocketClient.

The following snippet works fine:

```
WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
    client.execute(
            URI.create("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"),
            session -> {
                Flux<String> tradesFlux = session.receive()
                        .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                        .doOnNext(event -> log.info(event));

                return tradesFlux.then();
            }
).subscribe();
```

In the above snippet i use `doOnNext()` on the inbound stream Flux - `tradesFlux` to consume each event which is coming in. It works fine with the above snippet, but as far as i know, `doOnNext()` is a sideEffect-op, so i tried to do the following:

```
WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
    client.execute(
            URI.create("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"),
            session -> {
                Flux<String> tradesFlux = session.receive()
                        .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText);

                tradesFlux.subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        log.info("replicate binance trade {}", s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });

                return tradesFlux.then();
            }
).subscribe();
```

In the second snippet i tried to consume the inbound stream with a `Subscriber` by calling `subscribe` on the inbound stream - `tradesFlux`. But with this snippet i got following exception:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
```

Somehow one can not consume the inbound stream Flux by his own `Subscriber`, so the question i want to ask is: is the first snippet already the proper way to consume inbound stream of `ReactorNettyWebSocketClient` by using the sideEffect-op `doOnNext()` or i was missing something here?

Thank you very much!
Tung

Comment: Subscribe consumes, and what is returned is a disposable that cannot be subscribed to again. Logging (which you are doing) is a side effect, so using doOnNext is the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that this Websocket connection can not be subcribed twice, like the exception say. Solution for me is use `map` operation - actually chain of it on the inbound stream Flux to process the events on 1-to-1 basis. Afterwards it sounds stupid with the quetion above, but it was very confused for me that all examples about using `ReactorNettyWebSocketClient` i found always use `doOnNext()` to process the events from inbound stream.

The running code then looks like following:

```
@Bean
public WebSocketClient binanceTradesWS(Function<String, BinanceTrade> binanceTradeMapper,
                                       Function<BinanceTrade, Trade> binanceTradeReplicator) {
    WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
    client.execute(
            URI.create("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"),
            session -> {
                return session.receive()
                        .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                        .map(binanceTradeMapper)
                        .map(binanceTradeReplicator)
                        .then();
            }
    ).subscribe();

    return client;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new KotlinModule());
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    return mapper;
}

@Bean
public Function<String, BinanceTrade> binanceTradeMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return (String tradeJSON) -> {
        log.info("map binance trade {}", tradeJSON);
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(tradeJSON, BinanceTrade.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Function<BinanceTrade, Trade> binanceTradeReplicator() {
    return (BinanceTrade binanceTrade) -> {
        Trade trade =new Trade(
                binanceTrade.getT(),
                binanceTrade.getS(),
                new BigDecimal(binanceTrade.getQ()),
                new BigDecimal(binanceTrade.getP()),
                LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(binanceTrade.getTime()), TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT").toZoneId())
        );
        log.info("replicated binance trade {}", trade);
        return trade;
    };
}
```

**Update:**
After diving abit into the material i feel the way to handle Websocket connection of `ReactorNettyWebSocketClient#execute` is abit incompatible with it's reactive ecosystem. You have no way to forward it's inbound stream Flux to a reactive `KafkaSender` of module Reactor Kafka or to implement a `Supplier` function of this Flux in case on Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka-Binder. Because these both mechanism would call `subcribe` on the Flux and the exception mentioned above in question will be thrown.

Comment: I have a similar use case-I want to use ReactorNettyWebSocketClient to connect to different servers and I want to handle disconnects from the server (by reconnecting). Also did you manage to work out the reactive KafkaSender part? Like I would like to send the message to a Kafka topic after receiving it